# The source of and possible solutions for DEM anomalies?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, analysis, dem

I am working with a DSM (Digital Surface Model) created using stereo-paired spot 6/7 satellite imagery. This DSM, and metrics derived from it will be used to create a Predictive Ecosystem Map (PEM).

My problem is there appears to be two kinds of anomalies in the model. The first type appear as uniform "Bumps" throughout the DSM, the second appear as large "triangular" shaped polygons. These triangles mostly occur in relatively flat areas of the DSM, where-as the bumps appear almost everywhere else (See Photo B below).

[image: Photo A: Spot Imagery of Study Area]

[image: Photo B: DSM viewed with Hillshade]

Photo A shows the pan-sharpened true-color SPOT image of the study location, Photo B Shows the DSM viewed with Hillshade effect. Hillshade does exaggerate theses anomalies, however, the anomalies appear in other metrics created from the DSM.

My questions are:

1) Why are these anomalies not more uniform throughout the DSM if they are induced through sensor error, or what are the possible sources of these anomalies, and

2) What might be done to reduce the influence of these features when creating DSM metrics, and in the final analysis.

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what you mean by "bumps". Can you explain these further?

Comment: The "bumps" are the areas in the second image (Photo B) that appear as a rough surface texture in areas between the larger triangular shaped anomalies. However I know these features do not exist in the real landscape. My best guess is that this is noise from the sensor collecting the data. My problems is I don't understand why the landscape does not appear more uniform in the distribution of these anomalies. Either "bumpy" all over or "triangles" throughout, not the mix of the two anomalies seen in Photo B above.

Answer (score 1):

Note, this will not be a full answer to your questions. However, I will try to provide some ideas for question 2). I leave questions 1) to users that are more familiar with remote sensing techniques than I am.

---

**Ideas for question 2)**

I dont' think there is an out-of-the-box solution to the DSM creation / manipulation. You could try to:

- Use the `focal statistics` tool to smoothen the bumps and triangles. In order not to loose details in areas you find accurate, maybe create polygons for the processing extent. Personally, I like to use the "CIRCLE" search radius and "MEAN" processing option for such tasks. This is, in my eyes, the **most (time)-efficient** solution, specially if the relative changes between cells are only small. *However* be aware that this method might get rid of certain features you'd want in a DSM. So maybe have a closer look at one of the following options.
- Convert your raster into a `TIN` elevation model. Use the TIN-editing tools in order to get rid of all unwanted artefacts. Then convert back to a raster. This might be very time consuming. Also the conversions might negatively affect the accuracy of your data.
- Create `contours` with a small enough intervall of your original data. Edit these contours according to your needs. Then use the `topo to raster` tool and the edited contours as inputs. Use a boundary polygon in order to limit the processing extent to areas that need to be changed. Calculate the new raster. Use the `mosaic to new raster` or `raster calculator` tool to superimpose the corrected raster onto your original raster. Depending on your study area, this is also a time consuming option.

For detailed explanations of the methods mentioned, please refert to the ArcGIS Desktop (or online) help.